# How can one equation be used for both motions?

Tags: kinematics

In a kinematics question, where a ball is thrown up and it comes down and we have to calculate the total time for it, we can find it by breaking the motion into two parts, 1) going upwards, 2) going downwards, and then add each of their times to get total, BUT there is another, much more simpler way, where we can use s = 1/2 at² + ut just once for the whole motion, but how does that work? Coz acceleration changes from -g to +g when the ball changes direction, but we use only -g in the eq, and SUVAT eqs' requirement is that acc mustn't change.

Comment: The ball come down when the velocity is zero

Comment: Intuitively, gravity does not suddenly pull you in the opposite direction when you reach the apex of a jump. The only thing that has changed is your motion relative to it - on the way back down, gravity points the same direction as your velocity, rather than opposite it.

Comment: The acceleration of the ball is ALWAYS -g, even when the ball is going up.  And note that acceleration is definitely different than velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to illustrate the motion of the ball is to draw a velocity against time graph with up as the positive direction.

[image]

Note that the gradient of the graph (acceleration) is always $-g$.

The graph also illustrates the symmetry of the upward and downward motion.
Displacement up = - displacement down, displacement is equal to the area under the graph.
Initial velocity = - final velocity
Time up = time down = $\frac 12$ total time

Using the constant acceleration kinematic equations is an alternative method of solution without having to draw a graph.

Comment: Thank u very much, the graph helped!

Answer (score 6):

No, the acceleration does not change.  It's 9.8 m/s/s [down] on the way up and 9.8 m/s/s [down] on the way down.

In solving these sorts of accelerated motion problems one of the initial steps is decide which will be the positive direction.  It's good practice to state this explicitly.

Say we chose up as positive, then, for the projectile in question, initial velocity will be positive and acceleration will be negative.  The displacement will be positive if we are just considering the motion on the way up, or it will be zero if we are considering the whole up and down travel.

I suspect what you did when you solved for the time going up and the time coming down separately is that going up you took up as positive and going down you picked down as positive.  Since the acceleration is always down that would explain why it was negative for the first calculation and positive for the second.

Comment: But I studied that we input -9.81 in acc when the ball is going upwards and +9.81 when it is going downwards. I think that you mean that 'g' doesn't change, but 'a' does, as it is first -g then +g.

Comment: @MohammadAbdullahFarooqui I will edit my answer to explain.

Comment: No, he means that "a" doesn't change. a is constant throughout flight.

Comment: @Mohammad a does not change. It is -g the entire time, up and down. M Enns is correct, you are mistaken

Comment: Okay, thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, the acceleration doesn't change. It always points *down*, into the core of the earth.

Now, to answer you question, *how do we calculate the total time of the up+down trajectory in one go?*

Using the equation of motion:
$$ y_f = y_0 + v_0t -\frac{1}{2}gt^2,$$ where $y_0$ is your initial height, $y_f$ your final height, $v_0$ your initial velocity and $g=+9.81 \frac{m}{s}$ is the acceleration due to earth's gravity (notice that I'm taking it to be positive because in the equation I included the negative sign).

Now, notice that if the ball gets back to where it started, then $y_f = y_0$, and you get, after a little bit of algebra:
$$ t\left(v_0-\frac{1}{2}gt\right) = 0 $$
This equation has 2 solutions, one at $t=0$ because if no time has passed then its final position has to be the same as the starting position, and another one at:
$$ t_\text{total}= \frac{2v_0}{g} $$
**which is what you are looking for.**

Something extra: the uptime is the same as the downtime. You can see this with the equation of motion $v_f = v_0 - gt$, and because when the ball reaches its highest point then its velocity becomes zero, so $t_\text{up} = v_0/g$. You can see now from $t_\text{total}$ and $t_\text{up}$ that $t_\text{down}$ has to equal $t_\text{up}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!